# Azure AD client credentials flow permission grants

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

When using Azure AD client credentials flow, should the oauth2 endpoint (of azure ad) produce a bearer token if the client application has **NOT** been granted permission to access the requested resource?  I was certain it used to error in this case, but I'm now seeing different behavior (a valid bearer token is now provided even if the client application does **NOT** have permission to the resource application).

Answer (score 4):

We have always allowed tokens to be issues between two services when using the client credential flow. This scenario is basically S2S between Daemon Services.

The important thing to note here is that the built in authorization model for AAD takes advantage of `SCP` and `ROLE` claims, which appear in the token and can help your API understand what permissions it has been granted by the user.

However, we want to also allow you, in this situation, to use your own authorization layer. For example, you could simply white-list the App ID of the client application to allow it to make S2S calls to your API, without the presence of any `ROLE` claims in the token. The token issuance behavior here enables this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When you say "always allowed tokens to be issued", you mean Azure AD's behavior hasn't changed for client credentials flow in the original /oauth2/token endpoint, correct?  I work with a team of architects that recall Azure AD not providing a bearer token for resources an app didn't have access to.

Adding and requiring roles will work, but it adds a level of complexity since most of our IT staff is not a global admin or user admin of the directory (required to assign application roles).

Comment: To my memory, we always issued app only tokens, independent of the permissions selected for an app. We throw an error only when a user is interacting with the login experience.